# forward post or get string

Tags: php

I am building a php script which requires me to forward the post or get string that was sent to this script to the next one.
I was trying to figure out how I can forward this information to the next page - obviously I put

```
<form action="script.php?(previous get string)>
```

but the real question is - how do I retrieve the entire string - or is it not possible.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't a session, local storage, or cookie be easier?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can be both post of get, then you can save it into a session variable and get it in the next page like so:

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
$_SESSION['get'] = $_GET;
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$previous_post = $_SESSION['post'];
$previous_get = $_SESSION['get'];
?>
```

Comment: ha didnt think of it being that easy - I thought you had to define your get or post => I guess it really is just an array